# scrolling RecyclerView changes other data as well

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` to show the list of items. I have two `TextViews` one below other. Initially the second `TextView` is set to `singleline = true`.Now on item click, I am setting `singleline = false`. This is just done to expand it on click (Like `ExpandableList`). The code works fine but the problem is that as `RecyclerView` uses the recycled item other items TextView values are also being set to `singleline = false`. Now how can I avoid this?

Code

```
public class InboxAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InboxAdapter.InboxViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<InboxModel> listInbox;
    private InboxModel currentItem;

    public InboxAdapter(Context context, List<InboxModel> listInbox) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listInbox = listInbox;
    }

    @Override
    public InboxViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_inbox_item, parent, false);
        InboxViewHolder viewHolder = new InboxViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final InboxViewHolder holder, int position) {

        currentItem = listInbox.get(position);
        holder.tvHeader.setText(currentItem.header);
        holder.tvMsg.setText(currentItem.msg);

        holder.tvHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.tvMsg.setSingleLine(false);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.tvMsg.getLayoutParams();
                lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                holder.tvMsg.setLayoutParams(lp);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listInbox.size();
    }

    class InboxViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvImageHeader;
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private TextView tvMsg;
        private TextView tvDate;


        public InboxViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvImageHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_img_header);
            tvHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
            tvMsg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
            tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm For that you have to saved click postion and write condition in onBindViewHolder() like below

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final InboxViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(Postion==Mysavedposition){
      holder.tvMsg.setSingleLine(false);
    }else{
      holder.tvMsg.setSingleLine(true);
    }
            currentItem = listInbox.get(position);
            holder.tvHeader.setText(currentItem.header);
            holder.tvMsg.setText(currentItem.msg);

            holder.tvHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    Mysavedposition=position;
                    holder.tvMsg.setSingleLine(false);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.tvMsg.getLayoutParams();
                    lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    holder.tvMsg.setLayoutParams(lp);

                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the attribute in **all cases** to avoid issues with the recycled items.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final InboxViewHolder holder, int position){

   //....

   if (currentItem.myBoolean){
      holder.tvMsg.setSingleLine(true);
   } else {
      holder.tvMsg.setSingleLine(false);
   }

   //...
}
```

In your click event just change the value inside the object (not the view!). Somenthing like:

```
holder.tvHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    currentItem.myBoolean = true;
                    //call the notify !  
                }
            });
```

If this state is exclusive, instead of using a variable inside the item use a variable (InboxModel checkedItem) inside the Adapter.